# What's the first step to learn Verilog coding to sort values?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

I do not know how to start working on this problem. Should I first design the digital circuit of sorting? I am poor on both topic. Suppose I have four numbers R0, R1, R2, R3... What is the digital circuit for arranging these numbers in ascending order? I found a sorter circuit on the internet, but I'm not able to relate it to my problem.

[image]

Can anyone give me a hint regarding this?

Comment: The diagram shows a maximum finding network, not a sorter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic hardware sorting element is a module that has two inputs and two outputs. It contains a comparator and *two* multiplexers, and presents the smaller of the two inputs at one of its output ports, and the larger at the other output port.

There are many ways to use such a module to sort a list of items, with a wide range of space-vs.-time tradeoffs. At one extreme, you can build a completely combinatorial sorting network (with optional pipeline registers to increase throughput), but the resources required grows O(N<sup>2</sup>). I have implemented such a network to create a real-time median filter for high-definition video.

Comment: thans for giving me point ... my final objective is to do verilog code of median filter