# Bit compression in Verilog

Tags: verilog, multiplier

I am trying to write a Verilog code for a multiplier based on the abacus principle. I want to compress an array of 8X15 bits to the lowest rows. For e.g. for an array of

```
    p0 = 0000000000000000
    p1 = 1111111111111111
    p2 = 0000000000000000
    p3 = 1111111111111111
    p4 = 0000000000000000
    p5 = 1111111111111111
    p6 = 0000000000000000
    p7 = 1111111111111111
```

I want my output to be:

```
    pp[0] = 000000000000000
    pp[1] = 000000000000000
    pp[2] = 000000000000000
    pp[3] = 000000000000000
    pp[4] = 111111111111111
    pp[5] = 111111111111111
    pp[6] = 111111111111111
    pp[7] = 111111111111111
```

I have written the following code to accomplish this:

```
    always @ (p0 or p1 or p2 or p3 or p4 or p5 or p6 or p7)
 begin
 pp[1] = p0;
 pp[2] = p1;
 pp[3] = p2;
 pp[4] = p3;
 pp[5] = p4;
 pp[6] = p5;
 pp[7] = p6;
 pp[8] = p7;

for (i=1; i<=15; i=i+1)
 begin
    for (j=8; j>=1; j=j-1)
    begin
       for (k=j-1; k>=1; k=k-1)
          begin
          if ((!pp[j][i]) && (pp[k][i]))
            begin
            pp[j][i] <= pp[k][i];
            pp[k][i] <= pp[j][i];
            end
          end
      end
  end
end
```

but the output that I am getting is this:

```
    pp[0] = 000000000000000
    pp[1] = 000000000000000
    pp[2] = 111111111111111
    pp[3] = 000000000000000
    pp[4] = 111111111111111
    pp[5] = 000000000000000
    pp[6] = 111111111111111
    pp[7] = 111111111111111
```

Can someone please tell where the fault is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this to work if you replace the non-blocking assignments with blocking assignments.  It is still not readily synthesizable, but it would be OK as a testbench.  Example below.

Non-blocking assignments which use `<=` don't take effect immediately, but rather are delayed until a later point in time, which can be thought of as the end of the current time step.  Since all the for loops are inside the same time step, if they use non-blocking assignments, they schedule a series of events to occur at the end of the current time step.  So the`for j` and `for k` loops always see the initial values of the array.  As this algorithm is expressed, it is necessary for these two loops to be working with the data after the swap has occurred.

```
module compressMe();

  reg [15:0] p0;
  reg [15:0] p1;
  reg [15:0] p2;
  reg [15:0] p3;
  reg [15:0] p4;
  reg [15:0] p5;
  reg [15:0] p6;
  reg [15:0] p7;

  reg [15:0] pp [7:0];

  integer i,j,k;

  reg swapTemp;

  initial
    begin
      p0 <= 16'b0000000000000000;
      p1 <= 16'b1111111111111111;
      p2 <= 16'b0000000000000000;
      p3 <= 16'b1111111111111111;
      p4 <= 16'b0000000000000000;
      p5 <= 16'b1111111111111111;
      p6 <= 16'b0000000000000000;
      p7 <= 16'b1111111111111111;
  end

  always @ (p0 or p1 or p2 or p3 or p4 or p5 or p6 or p7)
    begin
    pp[0] = p0;
    pp[1] = p1;
    pp[2] = p2;
    pp[3] = p3;
    pp[4] = p4;
    pp[5] = p5;
    pp[6] = p6;
    pp[7] = p7;

    for (i=0; i<=15; i=i+1)
      begin
          for (j=7; j>=1; j=j-1)
          begin
            for (k=j-1; k>=1; k=k-1)c
                beginc
                if (    ( !pp[j][i] )     &&    (  pp[k][i]  )    )   
                  begin
                  swapTemp = pp[j][i];
                  pp[j][i] = pp[k][i];
                  pp[k][i] = swapTemp;
                  end
                end
            end
        end
  end


  initial
    begin
    #100 for (i=0; i<=7; i=i+1)
        $display("pp[%d] = %16b ", i, pp[i]);
    end


endmodule
```

This will produce:

```
 ncsim> run
 pp[          0] = 0000000000000000 
 pp[          1] = 0000000000000000 
 pp[          2] = 0000000000000000 
 pp[          3] = 0000000000000000 
 pp[          4] = 1111111111111111 
 pp[          5] = 1111111111111111 
 pp[          6] = 1111111111111111 
 pp[          7] = 1111111111111111
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're writing code that would be appropriate for a software programming language in a hardware description language.

Remember, in a HDL, a `for` loop describes parallel hardware constructs, not sequential processing steps.

In your case, the outer `for` loop is appropriate, since you want to build logic that handles each column independently. But within each column, you want to count the number of ones and then output a bit vector that has that many bits set in a row. The easiest way to specify this might be to simply enumerate all of the possibilities with a `case` statement or a lookup table.

If you really want to do it with logic, [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/99082/11683) may offer a clue. (You're basically sorting a list of 1-bit values.)